# I have the error: Command raised an exception: TypeError: wait_for() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot that responds when a message has a reaction

This is the line that has the error:

```
    confirmation = await Bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check)
```

This is the full code:

```
    import discord
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!") 



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.command(pass_context = "true")
async def ping(ctx):
    def check(reaction, user):
       return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["✅"] and reaction.message == message
    message = await ctx.send("Test emoji")
    await message.add_reaction("✅")
    confirmation = await Bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check) 
    channel = Bot.get_channel(704609444092182632)

    if confirmation:
        await channel.send("yay")


client.run(TOKEN)
```

When I run the !ping command I get the error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: wait_for() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a method of the class `Bot` which means you're supposed to run it on an **instance** of `commands.Bot`.

On line 6 you create an instance & call it `client` so instead of `Bot.wait_for`, which is the **class**, do `client.wait_for`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command(pass_context = "true")
async def ping(ctx):
    def check(reaction, user):
       return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["✅"] and reaction.message == message
    message = await ctx.send("Test emoji")
    await message.add_reaction("✅")
    confirmation = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=check) 


    if confirmation:
        await ctx.send("yay")
```

you dont need to add the channel check, just put `await ctx.send("yay")`
and the error code is referring to your `await Bot.wait_for`, your Bot is using `client` so you cant call `Bot`